Download 500 MB in android
I am writing an application to download 6 files of size 500 MB approx. I implemented the download manager and it was working fine but find a few issues in production like "Android DownloadManager doesn't work in some circumstances". Also there are multiple posts explaining download manager is not reliable. So I have to remove the download manager and write code to download the files.
What is the best approach in Android to download files of size 500 MB and show download progress?
Few available options are

Service
Work manager
Retrofit


Downloading data on Android is a bit hit and miss as the hardware is so varied, I would do tests on the three systems you mention and find the one that best suits what your trying to do.
On a personal experience I downloaded data for my game using the standard service but my data wasn't 500Mb.

An answer should solve the problem. Any other information should be given as a comment instead.
Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
